How to deduce that $\frac{\left| z\right| }{{\left( 1 + \left| z\right| \right) }^{2}} \leq \left| {f\left( z\right) }\right|$

Let $f$ is holomorphic in $B(0,1)$, $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$. How to deduce from $\frac{1 - \left| z\right| }{{\left( 1 + \left| z\right| \right) }^{3}} \leq  \left| {{f}^{\prime }\left( z\right) }\right|  \leq  \frac{1 + \left| z\right| }{{\left( 1 - \left| z\right| \right) }^{3}}, \forall z \in  B\left( {0, 1}\right)$ to $\frac{\left| z\right| }{{\left( 1 + \left| z\right| \right) }^{2}} \leq  \left| {f\left( z\right) }\right|  \leq  \frac{\left| z\right| }{{\left( 1 - \left| z\right| \right) }^{2}}, \forall z \in  B\left( {0, 1}\right)$.

See also Page 141-142 in https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math401.F09/Zorn.pdf
The right-hand side is easy
\begin{aligned}
|f(z)|=&\left|\int_0^z f'(\zeta)\mathrm{ d} \zeta\right|
\leq \int_0^r |f'(\zeta)|\cdot |\mathrm{ d} \zeta|
\leq \int_0^r \frac{1+\rho}{(1-\rho)^3}\mathrm{ d} \rho\\
=&\int_0^r \left[\frac{2}{(1-\rho)^3}-\frac{1}{(1-\rho)^2}\right]\mathrm{ d} \rho
=\frac{r}{(1-r)^2},
\end{aligned}
But the left-hand side is messy as the second inequality is $\leq$:
\begin{aligned}
|f(z)|=&\left|\int_0^z f'(\zeta)\mathrm{ d} \zeta\right|
\leq \int_0^r |f'(\zeta)|\cdot |\mathrm{ d} \zeta|
\geq \int_0^r \frac{1-\rho}{(1+\rho)^3}\mathrm{ d} \rho\\
=&\int_0^r \left[\frac{2}{(1+\rho)^3}-\frac{1}{(1+\rho)^2}\right]\mathrm{ d} \rho
=\frac{r}{(1+r)^2}.
\end{aligned}
How to fix it? Can we find a path so that $f'(\zeta)d\zeta\geq 0$?

That article does use (1) to prove (2). It says “The proof of (2) is similar.”

@MartinR But $|f(z)|\leq\cdots$ comes from $|f'(z)|\leq \cdots$. I see it clearly is right.

That does not mean that the lower bound for $|f(z)|$ can be concluded from the lower bound of $|f'(z)|$. It may be possible but it is not done in that article.

And perhaps you should mention that this is about functions in the class S (holomorphic and injective in the unit disk, $f(0) =0$, $f'(0) = 1$).

For the inequality $\frac{\left| z\right| }{{\left( 1 + \left| z\right| \right) }^{2}} \leq  \left| {f\left( z\right) }\right| $ one can assume wlog $|f(z)| <1/4$ since the LHS above is strictly less than $1/4$ when $|z|<1$.
Then by the Koebe theorem the radial segment $[0, f(z)]$ is included in the range of $f$ so $C$ its preimage is a simple arc from $0$ to $z$ and on $C$ with $\zeta=f^{-1}(w), d\zeta=dw/f'(\zeta)$ so one has $f'(\zeta)d\zeta=dw$ and noting that $|\int_0^{f(z)}dw|=\int_0^{|f(z)|}|dw|$  (since $w=re^{i\arg f(z)}$ implies $dw=e^{i\arg f(z)}dr, |dw|=dr$ etc) by change of variables it follows that with $\rho=|\zeta|$ $$|f(z)|=|\int_Cf'(\zeta)d\zeta|=\int_C|f'(\zeta)||d\zeta|\ge \int_0^{|z|}\frac{1-\rho}{(1+\rho)^3}d\rho=\frac{|z|}{(1+|z|)^2}$$

This is what I want to prove: $|f(z)|\geq\cdots$, the first line.

the proof above is the standard one for that (it first shows that one can assume $|f(z)|$ small as otherwise inequality trivially true and then one finds a path from $0$ to $z$ where the absolute value of the integral is indeed the integral of the absolute values as you surmised in the post)
